# Editing polygons in postgis layers

Tags: qgis, postgis

I am using qgis to create polygons in a postgis layer.  I can create polygons and save them without a problem, but I am unable to delete them or use the node tool to reposition the points of existing polygons.  Editing is enabled, but both the node tool and delete selected tool are greyed out (even when a feature in the current layer is selected):

[image]

I have seen posts elsewhere suggesting that these sorts of edits should be possible.  Is this a bug in the current release of qgis, or are these features simply not supported?

**Update**

It turns out I can't edit *any* attributes in the attribute table, not even when using the "add feature" button in the attribute table.

Comment: sounds like a permissions issue for the user you are logged in as, might not have delete permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if your table have column with *primary key*. If not you can add it this way:

`ALTER TABLE <schema>.<table> ADD COLUMN <column> bigserial primary key;`

It should solve your problem with editing. If not - there is propably permissions problem as @Mapperz said.

Comment: That (missing primary key) was totally it.  Thanks!